# How can define a function object in R language in R studio IDE

Tags: r, decision-tree

This might be a very basic question but I've just got started with decision trees using the R studio IDE and I'm not that familiar with the language yet,I think I have to define the object before but I'm not sure how to do so, any ideas please?

code:

```
create_train_test & lt;- function(data, size = 0.8, train = TRUE) {
n_row = nrow(data)
total_row = size * n_row
train_sample & lt; - 1: total_row
if (train == TRUE) {
return (data[train_sample, ])
} else {
return (data[-train_sample, ])
}
}
```

Error : object 'create_train_test' not found.

Any ideas, please?
Note: I did try "<-" instead of "& lt;-" but I got "Error: unexpected symbol"

Comment: The issue is `& lt;-` instead it would be `create_train_test <- function(data, size = 0.8, train = TRUE) {`  Also, there is `train_sample & lt; - 1: total_row` inside the function,  It could be an issue of copy/pasting i.e. it would  be `train_sample <- -1:total_row`

Comment: When you tried <-  what was the full error message about unexpected symbol?

Comment: Please check the following tutorials https://www.guru99.com/r-decision-trees.html https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html if you had issues following them post the issues. In general there are lots of simpler ways to create a training/testing data in R as in the tutorials without the need for custom function.

Comment: @G5W the rest is: unexpected symbol in "create_train_test <- function(data, size = 0.8, train = TRUE){ n_row = nrow(data) total_row". I have modified the (& lt;-) as akrun mentionned in the first comment yet I've got the same error.

Comment: Did you change _both_ `& lt ;` ?  Please change the code in your question to what you are using now.

Comment: @G5W Thank you for your help, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a result of change in symbol while copy/pasting.  Change the `& lt;` to `<-` in the function assignment and also inside the function and it should work

```
create_train_test <- function(data, size = 0.8, train = TRUE) {
    n_row <- nrow(data)
    total_row <- size * n_row
    train_sample <- 1:total_row
    if (train == TRUE) {
        return (data[train_sample, ])
      } else {
        return (data[-train_sample, ])
     }
   }


create_train_test(mtcars)
#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
```

Comment: thanks, it works well, I think the problem was that I had all code inline , how to go back in line in Rstudio in the console?

Comment: @Ayoub  I would create an R script and save it occasionally to avoid losing that info